# Will JComboBox work with generic type arraylist?

Tags: java

I'm attempting to get my `JComboBox` to work with a generic arraylist. My thought here is as follows, I'm going to use this `draw()` function to add different types of array lists to my JPanel instead of having a different function for different types of arraylists. Is this possible?

I just get the error `The constructor JComboBox<T>(ArrayList<T>) is undefined` which I believe is because I am not giving the JBoxCombo a specific type as expected?

```
public void draw(ArrayList<T> arrayList){

  //ERROR HERE (see description for error message)  
  JComboBox<T> ArrayListToJCombo = new JComboBox<T>(arrayList);

  //p1 (JPanel obj) initalized at the top of the class
  p1.add(ArrayListToJCombo);

  //frame (JFrame obj) inialized at the top of the class
  frame.add(p1);

  frame.setVisible(true);       

}
```

Comment: The problem is that `JComboBox` doesn't have a constructor that accepts an `ArrayList` : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html

Comment: It has a constructor that includes a vector, which includes list, which includes array list..right??

Comment: They both extend `java.util.AbstractList` , but `Vector` is not a  parent class of `ArrayList` .

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I run into these types of problems, I tend to write wrapper classes or extend the original class.  For instance, You can do something more like this:

```
public class MyJComboBox<T> extends JComboBox {
    ArrayList<T> list;
    public MyJComboBox<T>() {
        // Handle instantiation here, similar to what's done in JComboBox!
    }
}
```

or

```
public class MyJComboBox<T> {

    JComboBox jcb;
    ArrayList<T> list;
    public MyJComboBox<T>() {
        // Handle T in here
        this.jcb = new JComboBox();
    }
}
```

Extending is usually the cleaner solution, but I offered both because you will eventually run into classes that are "Final" and unable to be extended.

Comment: I have a question about this. So I currently have my class `createGraphics extends JFrame` and then if I create the wrapper glass would be `MyJComboBox extends JComboBox` how would the two classes interact with the same `JFrame` and `JPanels` (which would be created in the `createGraphics` class)?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question.  What's your goal here?

If you use the first example (you'll have to make sure the class is properly defined similar to the JComboBox... you'll need to particularly look at the constructor of the superclass.  Depending on which constructor you want, make a call to super() so that you can properly instantiate your class.  Start by making sure you can instantiate and use MyJComboBox exactly like a JComboBox, then move onto worrying about the modifications you want to make with respect to the generics.